# Xamarin.Form application does not want to work in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am starting to learn myself Xamarin.Forms in visual studio to start learning how to create mobile applications.
I have been following the following learning material and my question is about the learning material.
Get it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

In the book it says you have to start a project by selecting a Blank App(Portable Class Library) from Cross-platform in the c# section.

Now before even doing any coding(or anything for that matter) they request that you run the application( you can choose Android,iOS or Windows) just to see how it looks when you run the application(page 23 of the book).

Problem is when you run the application an actual android phone emulator shows up(like a real phone but just a software one where you can go to settings or Google or do whatever you can do on your normal phone) BUT in the book they say you will get the following emulator showing your App.cs code and not a phone emulator just emulator to test your mobile application with(see attached).

My confusion comes from the idea of when I want to test my program.Will the emulator show up or will my application which I want to design show up in the emulator(as this is not happening).Doesn't matter what I code in the App.cs file of the solution every time I run the Android part of my project the Android emulator shows up.

[image: Book emulator(what I need)]

[image: My emulator(what I have)]

Comment: you need to look at the output window when it is deploying the app to see what errors it is generating

Comment: Is there an app thats called like your app on the emulator device...? Maybe it's deployed but could've not been opened. (I've got that case sometimes) Otherwise do what @Jason says, watch and post the output.

Comment: what is your issue? 2nd picture is the expected Android emulator

Comment: The issue is I get an android emulator and now way of testing my code(or application I am trying to create).It does not exist as an app on the emulator or anything.The issue is I am getting a perfect working Android emulator BUT no way of testing my application.There is no option to open my application as an app on the emulator(and according to the book the application I am creating should be run immediately not an emulation of an perfect android device just an emulation of application on a Android device)